# Killing a background thread when a the fragment is destroyed

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments

i have an a fragment that have a background thread that update a progress bar value and change the progress bar drawable when the progress value reach a certain value when i try to start onther fragment in the same activity it case this error

```
    E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getResources()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.mego.adas.ui.CarFragment$PotProgressThread$1.run(CarFragment.java:831)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.mego.adas, PID: 25935
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getResources()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.mego.adas.ui.CarFragment$PotProgressThread$1.run(CarFragment.java:831)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

here is the code for the thread

```
    class PotProgressThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (potSensorValue <= 1025 && fragmentIsRunning) {

            if (fragmentIsRunning) {

                // Update the progress bar
                potProgressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        potProgressBar.setProgress((int) potSensorValue);
                        if (potSensorValue >= 800) {
                            potProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(getActivity().
                                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbarred));
                        } else {
                            potProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(getActivity().
                                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbarblue));

                        }
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here where i cast start my thread in onCreateView() method

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_car, container, false);
    initializeScreen(rootView);

    //check the internet connection
     connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();

        //set up the firebase
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        //get the references for the childes
        //the main child for the directions services
        carDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child(constant.FIREBASE_CAR);

        //the childes for the direction root
        connectionStateDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference()
                .child(constant.FIREBASE_CAR).child(constant.FIREBASE_CONNECTION_STATE);

        accidentStateDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference()
                .child(constant.FIREBASE_CAR).child(constant.FIREBASE_ACCIDENT_STATE);

        startStateStateDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference()
                .child(constant.FIREBASE_CAR).child(constant.FIREBASE_START_STATE);

        lightsStateDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference()
                .child(constant.FIREBASE_CAR).child(constant.FIREBASE_LIGHTS_STATE);

        lockStateDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference()
                .child(constant.FIREBASE_CAR).child(constant.FIREBASE_LOCK_STATE);

        mappingServicesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference()
                .child(constant.FIREBASE_CAR).child(constant.FIREBASE_MAPPING_SERVICES);

        sensorsValuesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference()
                .child(constant.FIREBASE_CAR).child(constant.FIREBASE_SENSORES_VALUES);

        connectionStateDatabaseReference.setValue(1);


    }
    //show Snackbar if there is no internet net connection
    else {
        if (carFragment != null) {

            //   Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(carFragment, R.string.no_internet_connection, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            // snackbar.show();
        }
    }

    //get the date from the connected thread
    bluetoothHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            //if message is what we want
            if (msg.what == handlerState) {
                // msg.arg1 = bytes from connect thread
                String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;

                //keep appending to string until ~ char
                recDataString.append(readMessage);

                //determine the end of the line
                endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~");
                if (fragmentIsRunning) {
                    refreshUI();
                }

            }
        }
    };

    //setup ans start the threads
    potThread = new Thread(new PotProgressThread());
    tempThread = new Thread(new TemperatureProgressThread());
    ldrThread = new Thread(new LdrProgressThread());


    fragmentIsRunning = true;
    potThread.start();
    tempThread.start();
    ldrThread.start();


    //set the buttons listener
    lightsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    lockButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    disconnectButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    //setup the map fragment
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_location_fragment_car);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}
```

Here is the code on onDestoryview() method

```
fragmentIsRunning = false;
potThread.interrupt();
```

how can i kill it

Comment: please share your `onCreateView()` method code.

Comment: ok i will edit the question

Comment: done check it  ..

Comment: the error happen when i leave the fragment and go to ather fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dalvik keeps all Thread references in the runtime so your thread will keep running unless it is terminated or completes (some [reference](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/activitys-threads-memory-leaks.html)). So depending on where you start your thread, you may be creating more than one.

In your case Your thread execution is not completed and you change the fragment so your `getActivity()` will be null.

The solution is before `getActivity()`, check `isAdded()` is true or not, if not true, that means the fragment is already detached, call to `getActivity()` will return null.

Remember in the Thread, everywhere before you call `getActivity()`, you'd better to check isAdded() again, because user may exit the activity at anytime during the Thread is executing.

> Other Solution

I am not sure but you can achieve by initialize `Context` globally and you that context in your thread.

```
Context mContext;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
     mContext = getActivity();
     ....
}
```

Now use this context in your thread.

```
class PotProgressThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (potSensorValue <= 1025 && fragmentIsRunning) {

            if (fragmentIsRunning) {

                // Update the progress bar
                potProgressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        potProgressBar.setProgress((int) potSensorValue);
                        if (potSensorValue >= 800) {
                            potProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(mContext.
                                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbarred));
                        } else {
                            potProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(mContext.
                                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbarblue));

                        }
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you will get the solution.

Comment: ok thank you very much very  for this the first soluation is work for me good i did't try the second but  i think it won't work because the error happen when i go to other fragment not when i start this fragment